# Converting from PyQt4 to PySide

Tags: python-2.7, pyqt4, pyside, maya

Maya 2014 supports PySide out of the box so I am looking to convert all of my existing tools (not many since I am pretty new to PyQt programming) from PyQt to PySide.

Does anyone know of a place that illustrates all of the differences? I have read a few places talking about the differences in regards to Signals, Slots, and a few of the objects that they got rid of (QString, etc.), is there anything else?

Also, I understand that PyQt4 API2 and PySide are quite similar. The issue here is that I am not sure if I am using API 1 or API 2, can anyone illustrate the difference between the two (I was having trouble finding documentation on this)?

Answer (score 4):

The general rule is:

- PyQt4 on python2 uses API v1
- PyQt4 on python3 used API v2

You can [select the API](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/incompatible_apis.html) version by using [`sip.setapi`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/sip4/python_api.html#sip.getapi) before importing any PyQt4 classes.
After importing PyQt4, you can query the api version using [`sip.getapi`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/sip4/python_api.html#sip.getapi)

The main differences are:

- `QString`:
    not available in v2 anymore, automatic conversion to `unicode` (py2) or `str` (py3)
- `QVariant`:
    can't be instantiated in v2, variants will be converted to/from python types
- `QDate`, `QDateTime`, `QTime` and `QUrl`:
    in v1, the `__hash__` method uses the object's id, in v2 it uses the object's
    string representation so objects with the same representation will return the
    same hash.
- `QTextStream`:
    methods which require a mutable string implementation (e.g. QString)
    are not implemented

More differences are listed [here](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/python_v3.html), usually the deprecation of `QString` is what has most impact on existing code. 
So, if you need to port code from PyQt4 (API v1) to PySide, i'd suggest to first make it compatible with PyQt4 (API v2). The rest should be a matter of changing import statements.